# Image scaling with CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

I don't actually need it now, but just out of curiosity...

Suppose we have a *fluid* website layout that works perfectly well on 1920px displays and on small smartphones. Now let's say we have images there and obviously (obviously?) we want to scale them. We've uploaded 2560px images on a server (because who cares about bandwidth nowadays) and set `width: 100%` property to the `img` tag.

So we have two users: a programmer with a 1920px display, let's call him Jo, and a female student with a smartphone, let's call her Nancy (because everything is better with Nancy, right?).

Jo and Nancy are happy because our plan with images scaling using `width: 100%` works, but what if we decided to show small images too, something like 400px width? Nancy won't notice anything, but for Jo it would be a disaster.

So the question is: can we make Jo and Nancy happy without using JavaScript?

Comment: What qualifies as making them happy? Also, serving 2560px images to smartphones is a terrible idea.

Comment: They will be happy if our image will scale at Nancy' smartphone and Jo will see 400px image, without scaling.

Comment: Do you mean you have set the image's width attribute to 100% as in `<img src="image.jpg" width="100%" />`?

Comment: @MrMisterMan, no, CSS as in `img { width: 100% }`

Comment: Use [slimmage.js or something similar that keys off `max-width` to select the right image](https://github.com/imazen/slimmage). Serving a 1920px image to a mobile device is a terrible idea; each megapixel of imagery uses ~16MB of mobile RAM. Regardless of bandwidth, that *will* crash phones.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why not go for the `max-width: 100%` instead?

This will leave all the images that are smaller than the width of the screen alone and the ones that are wider than the screen will be resized too 100%. Problem solved, everyones happy!

Comment: This is definitely the traditional way of doing images in responsive web design.

Comment: Because it would be too easy, of course! Actually, you answered my question, I've never used `max-width` with images but I tried now and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add that you seem to need to add a `height: auto` to the images to prevent the aspect ratios from becoming skewed (at least on the mobile browser I'm using now...)

Comment: which mobile browser is that?

Comment: Max-width: 100% does not always work on images unfortunately.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the correct answer. This answer relies on an interpretation of max-width:100% on an image as "image width shall not exceed the actual px width of this image". But as you can see on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp max-width:100% refers to 100% of the *container* element, not the element itself. So max-width:100% on an image actually means "image width shall not exceed the width of the container".. i.e. it will stretch to fill all available space, which is what the OP (and now I) wanted to avoid.

Comment: @rob Are your sure you're doing it right? Here's a quick jsfiddle to show that it actually works. http://jsfiddle.net/JVkpT/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send different pictures to different screens based on their widths, you should dive into those conditional media queries we keep hearing about.
This is a nice website: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: Thanks, I already use them almost everywhere. I just thought what if there would be a situation where I won't be able to use different pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I used `max-width: 100%` as Filip had mentioned, but I also needed to include:

`height:auto`

Otherwise the height wouldn't scale.